# pick an element in a dynamic array without repetition in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to create dynamically an array where the size and the content are variables:

```
Array[Size] = [E1, E2, E3, .., En]
with  E0 = Const*n, E1 = Const*1, .., En = Const*n (n= Size-1),
```

Each time I want to pick an element from this array  without repetition.

Is there any efficient way to do it?
I thought using random function but it seems not possible because it may return the same element.

Comment: Are you talking about a sequence like 1,2,3,... or 3,6,9,... for instance because that is what it looks like?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1540257-remove

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, yes from 0 to Size-1 with 1 as step.

Comment: So `Array(0..<size)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include `0*constant`:

```swift
let arr = Array(0..<size).map { $0 * constant }
```

If you don't want to (i.e., start at `1*constant`):

```swift
let arr = Array(1..<size).map { $0 * constant }
```

If you don't want to multiply by a constant (or the constant is `1`):

```swift
let arr = Array(0..<size)
```